# Why does SignalR connection fail on .NET 8?

Tags: signalr, .net-8.0

I just moved from .NET 7 to .NET 8.

Now my SignalR code does not work anymore. Everything was fine on .NET 7.

Here is my client code:

```js
<script>

  var hub = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("/hub")
    .withAutomaticReconnect()
    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Debug)
    .build();;

var initMessaging = async function() {
  try {
    console.log("Before hub.start()")
    await hub.start()
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Hub connection established");       
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error("[1]:", err);
      });
    console.log("After hub.start()")
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("[2]:", err);
  }
}

$(function() {
  initWhenReadyMessaging();
});

</script>
```

Here is the relevant part from my C# Program.cs:

```js
...
services.AddSignalR();
...
var desiredTransports = HttpTransportType.WebSockets | HttpTransportType.LongPolling;
app.MapHub<SignalRHub>("/hub", (options) =>
{
    options.Transports = desiredTransports;
});
```

And here a screenshot from my browser's error console:

[image]

The error occurs during **hub.start()**. And I have no idea if this is a bug in .NET 8 or if I am doing something wrong.

This is my server: Windows Server 2019 Standard, IIS 10.0.17763.1, .NET 8.0.0 Windows Server Hosting bundle, @microsoft/signalr@8.0.0, jQuery 3.7.1

When I run my app inside Visual Studio 2022 (on Win 11), everything is fine. No errors, no problems.

I hope someone has a good idea or suggestion ...

Comment: Do you have the error from the backend?

Comment: I don't know. How could I find out?

Comment: TBH it is hard to tell - check out the app and/or IIS logs

Comment: Note that there was some breaking change related to trimming - see [TrimMode defaults to full for Web SDK projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/8.0/trimmode-full) - check if you publish with `PublishTrimmed=true` try adding `<TrimMode>partial</TrimMode>`

Comment: I beleive I founbd the error. I had some middleware that tried to access a write locked file. Since I removed the corresponding file, all of a sudden all my SignalR stuff works again. In other words: my own fault. Nothing to do with .NET 8. Thank you for your help, Guru Stron!